# Cadeia de entrada não estava em um formato incorreto

Tags: c#

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando criar um gráfico geométrico buscando de uma arquivo Txt porem ao iniciar o aplicativo aparece esse erro sou meio iniciante e estou com dificuldades para encontrar a solução

Comment: Poste seu código como texto aqui e tenha certeza que detalhou tudo o que era necessário sobre o problema para que as pessoas possam te ajudar. Sugiro começar fazendo coisas simples, conforme for dominando vai pegando outras coisas mais complicadas. Começar pelo complicado não aprende nada.

Answer (score 1):

Seu erro é porque você esta tentando converte um valor inexistente para o tipo `INT`, com isso você recebe o erro;

```
Run-time exception (line XXX): Input string was not in a correct format.
Stack Trace:
```

Uma forma de corrigir isso seria você verficar se realmente é um valor do tipo int antes de convertelo, isso pode ser feito da seguinte forma.

```
int number;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(texto10, out number);
```

Veja mais detalhes [aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k3LjJj), as linhas comentadas é o exemplo do seu erro.

Answer (score 0):

verifique o conteúdo da string antes de converte-la para Int32, 
o formato numérico não pode conter espaços ou vírgulas, nem mesmo estar vazio.

coloque um breakpoint nesta linha para verificar o valor da variável no momento da execução.